# An error occurs during the build process in a spring project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, compilation, querydsl

inteliJ 2022.3.2
gradle 7.6 version

<build.gradle>

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
}

group = 'heyuniverse'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
//    implementation 'ch.pete.appconfig:appconfig:0.1.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.15.0-GA'

    // === QueryDsl
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${dependencyManagement.importedProperties['querydsl.version']}:jakarta"
//    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
    annotationProcessor "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api"
    annotationProcessor "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api"

    //JWT
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-api', version: '0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-impl', version: '0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-jackson', version: '0.11.2'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

def querydslDir = "$buildDir/generated/querydsl"


clean {
    delete file("build/generated")
}

querydsl {
    library = "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt"
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = querydslDir
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir querydslDir
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

I am developing a web application using the above development environment.

I am able to create and run QClasses using compileQuerydsl locally, but when I try to build using gradle to create a jar file for deployment, I encounter the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4s


error: Attempt to recreate a file for type xxx.xxx.QClass


error: Attempt to recreate a file for type xxx.xxx.QClass


error: Attempt to recreate a file for type xxx.xxx.QClass


error: Attempt to recreate a file for type xxx.xxx.QClass
```

I have tried various solutions, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Could you please advise me on what might be causing the issue? Thank you so much in advance.

I have tried various methods such as modifying the script in different ways and clearing the caches of IDE and Gradle, but I have not been able to obtain any results.